# Issue with scale option in windows azure websites (WAWS)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have multiple websites in my windows azure account, all are required to run in **FREE** mode. for one website i need to change scale option from **Free to Reserved** however all my websites will get affected with same scaling.

Why this happens?

Is there any specific reason for this type of behavior?

If so then how it would be charged for 5 websites when only 1 requires to run in Reserved Mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it works today: When you change from *free* to *reserved*, all of your web sites are converted to *reserved*. They will also all run on the same set of VM instances. So: If you go with a single Small VM reserved, you're paying for one Small VM, even though *all* web sites are now running in your reserved VM. And... if you convert back to free mode, all your sites convert back to free mode.

There's also a *shared* tier. ScottGu [blogged about this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/09/17/announcing-great-improvements-to-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx) a while back.

Comment: Nice feature.. Thanks!

Comment: Yep--the thought is to give you the bonus of Reserved for all your sites if you upgrade one.

Comment: What if i would like to keep some websites on reserved & and some on free mode. in short can i have different VMs to running different websites or cloud service is alternative for that?